# Replacing list elements that satisfy some condition with items from another list in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have those two lists

```
a=[0,1,6,4,2,8] 
b=[10,20,30,40]
```

I want to replace elements in list a that are between 0 and 4 with items from list b.

In other words, my output should be

```
[10,20,6,30,40,8]
```

Note that essentially, we *strip* list `a` of elements satisfying a certain condition and simply replacing it with an item from list b onto this. (The ordering in b is maintained)

**EDIT**

I actually know that exactly N number of items in list `a` satisfy the condition imposed. Then I need to "replace" these in-place with another list b of size N.

Comment: is ordering important ? Could the output be `[6, 8, 10, 20, 30, 40]` ?

Comment: Ordering is essential, the output should exactly as shown

Comment: I actually know that exactly N number of items in list a satisfy the condition imposed. Then I need to "replace" these in-place with another list b of size N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this.

```
list1=[0,1,6,4,2,8]
list2=[10,20,30,40]
j=0
ans=[0]*len(list1)
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] <= 4:
        ans[list1.index(list1[i])]+=list2[j]
        if(j<len(list2)):
            j+=1
    else:
        ans[i]+=list1[i]

print(ans)
```

that should work.

Comment: I get the idea thanks. Also, your code seems to have a number of syntactical errors. Is this because of a different python version

Comment: i have made the changes you can run this code it will work fine on python 3.6

Comment: @RamanMishra Make sure to value readability when you code. In fact, ask yourself if you were a complete stranger looking at your code would you understand what is the purpose of it?

Comment: yaa actually you are right and it's just because it's been a while i used python that's why my code is bit  mess i will try to make it more readable thanks for feedback. @scharette

Answer (score 5):

Considering your edit, I would suggest using this simple and readable for loop.

```
a=[0,1,6,4,2,8] 
b=[10,20,30,40]
upper_bound = 4
lower_bound = 0
exclusions = range(lower_bound,upper_bound+1)

for index,item in enumerate(a):
  if item in exclusions:
    a[index] = b.pop(0)

print(a)
>>>>[10, 20, 6, 30, 40, 8]
```

---

Basically, here I'm iterating over a copy of the `a` list and once I find an item in the range of my specified bounds I pop the first element of `b` feeding it back to `a`.

**Important Note**

It is important to understand that I used an `exclusions` list, which I agree can be ommitted in your particular case, in order to allow someone to add `string` objects to the list and still have the same kind of behavior. Obviously, you could use something like,

```
if item > lower_bound and item < upper_bound
```

Which would be more efficient for your specific case since you're not creating an unecessary list.

---

**To answer @Julian concerns**, let's say your lists becomes `string` objects,

```
a=['a','b','c','d','e','f'] 
b=['test','test','test','test']
```

And instead of replace `0` to `4`, you want to replace a `c` to `f`. With my solution it would go like this,

```
exclusions = ['c','d','e','f']

for index,item in enumerate(a):
    if item in exclusions:
    a[index] = b.pop(0)

print(a)
>>>>['a', 'b', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test']
```

With @Julian answer,

```
b_iter = iter(b)
print([item if item < 0 or item > 4 else b_iter.next() for item in a])
>>>> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Now as he said, `>` and `<` operators can be used to compare two strings, so I mean he could go and change his comparisons to `string` type,

```
b_iter = iter(b)
print([item if item < '0' or item > '4' else b_iter.next() for item in a])
>>>>['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

that would still be completely wrong because comparing objects other than `int` or `float` with `<` and `>` makes no sense in the context of OP's question.

Also, it becomes even more apparent when you use other types,

```
a=[{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5},{5,6},{6,7}] 
b=[{'test'},{'test'},{'test'},{'test'}]

exclusions = [{3,4},{4,5},{5,6},{6,7}]

for index,item in enumerate(a):
  if item in exclusions:
    a[index] = b.pop(0)

print(a)
>>>> [{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {'test'}, {'test'}, {'test'}, {'test'}]

b_iter = iter(b)
print([item if item < 0 or item > 4 else b_iter.next() for item in a])
>>>> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'set' and 'int'
```

Now, I wouldn't know how he would go and fix that following his logic.

So as I said, in his comment section, make sure to be aware of what his answer implies.

Comment: it's a nice one 1 up

Comment: you don't need the `[:]` in `enumerate` just `a`. I would say this is the more Pythonic answer

Comment: I was gonna say that I prefer the `exclusion` syntax for readability at a small cost of creating an extra list. But your enumerate feedback is really interesting. Are we sure about it though. Could give a lit bit more insight on to why I don't need to iterate over a copy when using enumerate ?

Comment: @JGreenwell I actually opened a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51601249/7692463) about it since I really want to understand.

Comment: enumerate is a generator so it will just take a sequence (any sequence or iterator actually) and just "generates" an incrementing index to be yielded with each item from the passed sequence (so it's not making a copy anyway just an enumerate object which it is moving through). If you want to know more check out the [PEP from when it was added](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/). The exclusion is fine (actually I thought about it and it depends on too many things whether I would use an exclusion range or try/except)

Comment: This is not very efficient from a memory standpoint.  Imagine if `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` have a HUGE difference between them.  You would need to store a list that large in memory and each item for existence in that list every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: @julian I entirely agree with you. But I like to think that people should care about performance and memory when it really matters. My idea of creating a list was to allow op to use a similar logic using other types like `string` for example. I made it general and readable because the question title is general and that could ne benificial for future users.

Comment: @scharette right, but instead of creating a list for basically no reason, what would be cleaner is simply doing comparisons in place: like `if item < lower_bound or item > upper_bound:` instead of creating the `exclusions` list and performing an `<a> in <b>:` comparison

Comment: @Julian read my above comment or the one your answer. I think you'll get what I wanted to provide as an answer. Also added a note.

Comment: Note, just an fyi not a big deal, for Python 3 you need `next(b_iter)` instead of `b_iter.next()`- the next operator was dropped for the function - for the list comprehension to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter on your list b, and an if statement to replace only numbers less than 4:

```
a=[0,1,6,4,2,8]
b=[10,20,30,40]
n=0

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] <= 4 and a[i] >= 0:
        a[i] = b[n]
        n += 1
```

Comment: You're missing a `)`

Comment: What if `a` have `-1` in it ?

Comment: You could change the condition statement to be a[i] > 0 and a[i] <= 4

Comment: I know, my point was that OP asked for 0 to 4 which is what you should handle.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm pretty new to this website

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more compact and readable code for you.

```
a = [0, 1, 6, 4, 2, 8]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40]

temp = b
c = []
for item in a:
    if 0 <= item <= 4:
        c.append(temp.pop(0))
    else:
        c.append(item)

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions and an iterator to accomplish this in two lines:

```
>>> b_iter = iter(b)
>>> [item if item < 0 or item > 4 else b_iter.next() for item in a]
[10, 20, 6, 30, 40, 8]
```

This is all assuming your assumption that `a` contains `N` items where `0 < item < 4` and that the length of `b` is also exactly `N`.

This method has two benefits to the most highly upvoted answer here:

1. There is no need for an `exclusions` list, which is just a waste of memory.
2. This does not modify the `a` list, which could lead to issues if that is not what you are meaning to do.

Comment: 1) You should note that this only works for `int` type and is at the cost of readabilty over my answer.

Comment: 2) I'm modifying the `a` list because this is what OP is asking (_we strip list a of elements satisfying a certain condition and simply replacing it with an item from list b onto this._). He gains nothing more from your answer if this statement is correct.

Comment: @scharette not only are you incorrect, but you are incorrect in two different ways...
1) the solution I proposed does NOT only work for `int`, in fact it works for `float`, `int`, `str`, or anything else that can be compared with `<` or `>`
2) Your solution DOES in fact only work for `int` as `range` specifically returns a value of integers see the help text for range...
`range(start, stop[, step]) -> list of integers`

Comment: I used `range()` because the specific case of OP needed handling for `int` and it is a neat way of create a **list of ints**. But in my answer you could use `string` type like a **list of words** and it would still work. In your case, you're right that `str` support `<` but this is not in any way the behavior that someone would want. I mean, the goal is to replace certain values that you can specify in my `exclusions` list. Your answer would compare two string values with the `<` which is completely odd in the context of OP.

Comment: As I said above above, your answer is efficient, but specific to `int`  and possibly `float` values and you should definitely disclaim it. Now, if you decide not to, I can't suggest something else to improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: In fact, I went and edit my answer so you can have better understanding of my point. Hope it clarifies !

Answer (score -1):

The main concept behind solving this is to iterate through list a, check to see if each value achieves a certain condition (in this case, being between 0 and 4), and if so, replace that value with the corresponding value from b. You can use a for-loop and if statements to achieve this.

```
for i in range(len(a) + 1):   # where a is your first list
    if a[i]==1: #checking a specific index of the list
        a[i] = 10
    elif a[i] == 2:
        a[i] = 20
    elif a[i] == 3:
        a[i] == 30
    elif a[i] == 4:
        a[i] == 40
    else:
        continue
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You state that the OP only wants to replace the item based on a condition (between 0 & 4) but then your code fails to check this. Also, a set of if/elif/else statements can indicate that you either need a dictionary or to re-look at your logic. I would check out [Jay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600485/replacing-list-elements-that-satisfy-some-condition-with-items-from-another-list/51600895#51600895) as it is a straight-forward look at the logic for replacing this with just a single if and counter variable. (note: did not downvote but code needs to work or show concept)