# why this logic isn't run to end of list?

Tags: python, algorithm

this is the input value for logic

```
participant = ['leo', 'kiki', 'eden']
completion = ['eden', 'kiki']
```

and this is my source code to find word which is can't matching which In a mutual list

```
for i in participant:
    for j in completion:
        if i == j:
            participant.remove(i)
            completion.remove(i)
```

why this source code doesn't run to end of list element 'eden'?

currently result is it.

```
['leo', 'eden']
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601249/should-i-create-a-copy-when-iterating-over-a-list-using-enumerate-in-python, but I'm not sure if there's a better version of it.

Comment: You shouldn't add/remove from a list while iterating over the same list.

Answer (score 3):

From the python documentation:

> If you need to modify the sequence you are iterating over while inside the loop (for example to duplicate selected items), it is recommended that you first make a copy. Iterating over a sequence does not implicitly make a copy. The slice notation makes this especially convenient:
>
> ```
> >>> for w in words[:]:  # Loop over a slice copy of the entire list.
> ...     if len(w) > 6:
> ...         words.insert(0, w)
> ...
> >>> words
> ['defenestrate', 'cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
> ```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: Probably a good idea to ref the Python 3 docs over 2.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `participant` and `completion` are modified during your loop.
Try this code. It makes copy of the lists and not change the original ones but the copied ones.

```
import copy
participant = ['leo', 'kiki', 'eden']
completion = ['eden', 'kiki']

participant_copy = copy.copy(participant)
completion_copy = copy.copy(completion)
for i in participant:
    for j in completion:
        if i == j:
            participant_copy.remove(i)
            completion_copy.remove(j)
```

Comment: if i want to get a same result as like your code to use only one list (don't use copy list), how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution is to make use of the *slice* approach, like this, it will be very similar to what you have but slight difference:

Note: this uses the same iterator to go through the list for checking of common items.

```
participant = ['leo', 'kiki', 'eden']
completion = ['eden', 'kiki']

for i in participant[:]:
  if i in completion:
    participant.remove(i)
    completion.remove(i)

print(participant)
print(completion)
```

Output:

```
 ['leo'] #only one non-similar element left
 [] #completion is empty list now
```